# InfoPath - Delete specific repeating section

Tags: infopath

I have recently been tasked of extending the add/remove functions for repeating sections within an InfoPath form. Primarily because the default look is pretty ugly and unintuitive.

What I want to do is to place a "remove" button within each of the repeating sections, which when clicked will remove that section. This seemingly simple task does not appear to be all that simple in InfoPath.

Does anyone know how I would go about such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

Removing the whole repeating section? or line in that section?

For the whole repeating section, try hiding rule it by putting it inside another section.

Comment: I have decided to add a IsDeleted flag to the repeating group, which I set to true and hide the entire section if the button has been pressed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box rule that will delete the section.

You could use code for this - write code that deletes the instance of the group when the button is clicked.

You could also leverage Mekalikot's suggestion - add a field called "hide" or something in your repeating group and when the user clicks "Remove" set "hide" to true. Add conditional formatting to hide the repeating section if "hide" = true.